# Insufficient privileges error in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am new to using Oracle database. I worked on it for some weeks. It worked well. But now, I'm having some problem. I am getting this error while trying to connect. I didn't change the password. I am using the default user name and password only.

```
SQL> connect as sysdba
Enter user-name: SCOTT
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Can someone tell the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

That's because SCOTT isn't granted a SYSDBA role. Have a look at his demonstration.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> connect as sysdba
Enter user-name: scott
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL>
```

Connect as a privileged user (SYS) and grant SYSDBA to SCOTT:

```
SQL> connect as sysdba
Enter user-name: sys
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>
SQL> grant sysdba to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

OK; now, back to the initial attempt:

```
SQL> connect as sysdba
Enter user-name: scott
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>
```

Not everyone has SYSDBA privileges, and not everyone should have them. *Handle with care*, it is a powerful privilege so I'll revoke it from SCOTT:

```
SQL> connect as sysdba
Enter user-name: sys
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> revoke sysdba from scott;

Revoke succeeded.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share more information like OS etc

But have you checked user you are using to connect is part of ORA_DBA group assuming you are on windows